# Moving from AIDE to Eclipse--Preview Won't Show

Tags: android, eclipse, aide-ide

I've learned quite a lot about Android Java and XML and how to develop for Android by using AIDE and the various Internet sources that I have used, but I have one issue that is becoming a road block in my development: I have recently got my first laptop and I decided to get the SDK from Android Developers so I could continue working on my Android apps, and so I moved my App folder from my Android Device to the Folder I had set out as where Eclipse stores the apps, but when I load the Layout XML files on Eclipse, all I get is two tabs: Structure and the file name, but no Graphical Layout so I can preview what is going on. Can anybody explain why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the SDK properly installed, try right clicking the XML file in the Project Explorer, select Open With, then Android Common XML Editor. It's probably opening in the default XML editor right now.